# Can I use avcodec_free_context() on an opened context?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

The latest documentation says [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/group__lavc__core.html#gaf4daa92361efb3523ef5afeb0b54077f) that opening a context that's closed again is not supported any more. I see why. Some codecs don't work properly when they're reopened. So after finding this bug, I decided to not use `avcodec_close()` and call `avcodec_free_context()` on the contexts right away instead.

But I'm not sure if it's safe to do so with **2.8.4**, the version that I linked to my program. The documentation from that time doesn't clarify. Does anyone know? At least empirically?

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built with Microsoft (R) C/C++ 최적화 컴파일러 버전 18.00.31101(x64)
configuration: --toolchain=msvc --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-debug --extra-cflags=-MT --extra-cxxflags=-MT --extra-ldflags='/nodefaultlib:msvcrt.lib' --extra-libs='zlib.lib libogg_static.lib libvorbis_static.lib libmpghip-static.lib libmp3lame-static.lib libtheora_static.lib libx264.lib x265-static.lib libxvidcore.lib silk_fixed.lib silk_common.lib silk_float.lib celt.lib opus.lib vpxmt.lib'
libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

I know there's a bunch of forums I could post on but I'd felt like to ask it here first.

Comment: I also know that I could just compile the latest version to link that to my program. Done that. The API changed too much that it doesn't compile.

Comment: *"Use avcodec_free_context() to destroy a codec context (either **open** or closed)."* I think that fairly clearly means you can use it on an opened context.

Comment: @Kninnug Not on version 2.8 doc. You one of those dyslexic commenters again?